# How do you create a multi-attribute table and link to the main table?

Tags: oracle, database-design, one-to-many

I have a table called customer. The customer, Here are the details for the table

```
Table name: customers
Attributes: 
           cus_id -- primary key
           cus_street_num -- multi-attribute (home_address)
           cus_street_name -- multi-attribute (home_address)
           cus_suburb -- multi-attribute (home_address)
           cus_gender
```

Here us my code for the customer table creation. But how do I create the multi-attribute and link it to the customer table?

What is a multi-attribute? For example a home address is a multi-attribute. Why? Because a home address is made up of 3 components. The street number, the street name and the suburb. These 3 things can be separate attributes, but they are useless without if they aren't together. However, together, they make up the home address.

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    cus_id        NUMBER(5,0)
                  CONSTRAINT cus_id_pk
                  PRIMARY KEY (cus_id),
    cus_gender    NUMBER(1,0)
);
```

Comment: What is a "multi-attribute"?  If you are looking for record types, then MySQL does not support them.  Also, what is `NUMBER(1, 0)`?  That is definitely not MySQL syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally added mysql. I meant sql. Multi-attribute is like an address. It has the street number, street name, suburb etc

Comment: Haven't I seen this yesterday in another question? The OP had some ERD there. So it's probably the best to first ask the source of that ERD what is meant by multi-attribute.

Comment: @stickybit I edited my post and added a definition of multi-attribute

Comment: Your "multi attributes" need to be stored separately in different columns and added together when needed, maybe with a view. Another possibility as Gordon mentioned is using user defined types.

Comment: I'd say just add three columns to the table. Maybe add some check constraint, e.g. the street name mustn't be null if the street number is not null if such rules apply. As a bonus you could also use views or computed columns concatenating the values. But that depends on the DBMS and what this is actually for. Sounds more like some school exercise where the constraints and views etc. might be overkill.

Comment: @stickybit this is for school. I am using oracle. Could you give me an example? My actual er diagram has a lot more info and a lot of multi-attributes, but I just made this question only have a little bit of info for explain purposes

Comment: Just add the columns (one for each singles attribute of the "multi-attribute") like you did with the others to your `CREATE TABLE` statement. I think the additional stuff is to much, if this is for school. Unless they specifically taught you that, which I doubt.